# How do I make a drop down box on one sheet, based on non static cell values on another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make a drop down box on one sheet, based on non static cell values on another sheet!?

I am trying to create workbook where I can copy CSV data files from various scientific instruments for varying parameters and place the data on Sheet2. On sheet1 I'm going to have several columns that pull over the data I want to graph, and have the graph built into Sheet1. My issue is getting the drop down list to display the headers of the copied data from Sheet2 as options. The format on Sheet 2 is not static as all of the CSV files have been formatted differently per instrument.

I have used the macro from the article listed below to pull the columns over based on header. I dont' know all the potential headings of all the instruments I'll be working on. Can I set the Drop Down box to list the values of cells Sheet2!A1:P1 as options without setting Sheet2!A1:P1 as a table? (The users of this file will not grasp making a new table for every copy/paste of CSV data)

I am not going to be able to convert the data on Sheet2 into a table due to the potential mistakes of instructors in real time. (I'm creating this workbook for a training program. This is for the importance of data and not an excel class, as the instructors are not proficient with excel).

[Excel - How populate a column from another sheet based on unique column header names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617096/excel-how-populate-a-column-from-another-sheet-based-on-unique-column-header-n)

Answer (score 0):

In your Excel, create a named range:

- In Excel 2003 or lower -> Insert -> Name -> Define
- In Excel 2007 and higher -> Formulas -> Define Name

You can name it whatever you want, I would name it something like `listHeaders`

Use this formula to define it:

```
=Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1,,COUNTA(Sheet2!$1:$1))
```

Then for the drop down list, use Data Validation -> List and set the Source to be:

```
=listHeaders
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question. I had my headings I was importing to Sheet 2. I went to Sheet 3 and had Sheet3!A1=Sheet2!A1  then Sheet3!B1=Sheet2!B2 etc.  I used that range and created a named range. Then I went to Sheet1!A1 and assigned the drop down from the named range I created on Sheet3. I did the same for Sheet1!B1 and Sheet1!C1.  I then added the following Code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, nCol As Long
    Dim sSrch As String
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
        sSrch = Cells(1, Target.Column).Value

        Set aCell = wsI.Rows(1).Find(What:=sSrch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            nCol = aCell.Column

            lRow = wsI.Cells(wsI.Rows.Count, nCol).End(xlUp).Row

            Set rng = wsI.Range(wsI.Cells(2, nCol), wsI.Cells(lRow, nCol))
        End If

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(2, Target.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column)).ClearContents
            rng.Copy Cells(2, Target.Column)
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Now When I use the Sheet1!A1 drop down, it pulls from the Dynamic list on Sheet3 and the VBA coding pulls in the data for the column on Sheet2 that matches Sheet1!A1 selection.  This macro allows the columns to be pulled into the first 3 rows of Sheet1 depending on what is selected from the drop down.